# Scheduled Job Type C

Tags: scheduled-job

I can see a job of type "C" running in my Prod org and its id begins with "02L". Unfortunately I can not find what 02L means from [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000325244&type=1), so it isn't something standard, and there is no mention of a job type C [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_cronjobdetail.htm).
Is it a missed documentation?
Can anyone throw some light on this?

Comment: Daniel Ballinger has a fantastic resource that lists obscure ID prefixes, which you'll find [here](https://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#02L) (link set to highlight 02L). This is "DataflowVersion /MH_CUSTOMER_CRITERION". This makes me wonder if this is a scheduled execution for a flow?

Comment: Thanks for the link @Phil W, very helpful. I am not sure if it is a flow, all the flows we have are coming up as type "Scheduled Flow" in Scheduled Job List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that this is an internal type that Salesforce uses.

I've tried to divine this by the following.

## Describe Picklist Values

```
for(PicklistEntry value: CronJobDetail.JobType.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()) {
    System.debug(value.getValue()+':'+value.getLabel());
}
```

Value "C" doesn't appear in my list (but try it in your org, it might work).

## Id Sniffing

I've tried everything from my bag of tricks in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/239075/2984), and nothing turns up.

So, it must be something internal to Salesforce, or related to a feature you've enabled, or might even be a pilot/prerelease feature. Unfortunately, I don't think we have much more we can offer you.

However, you may not want to accept this answer quite yet; maybe someone can come up with an alternative solution or might happen to know more. You might also want to contact support if you need to know more, they might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, both for this answer and the link to the other one, very helpful. as for PicklistEntries, my org too returns only the documented ones, i.e. till A, Reporting Notification. I have now raised a case with Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

It stands for **Scheduled ELT Dataflow** and is related to [Dataflow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_integrate_dataflow_configure_editor.htm&type=5) for Tableau CRM. This was documented under `JobType` for [CronJobDetail](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_cronjobdetail.htm), but seems to have disappeared from being mentioned after API 46.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar thing in our Salsforce org.  Looking at the job create date and previous/next run time this appears to be tied to data refreshes that happen in the Tableau CRM Analytics Studio (https://[your org domain].lightning.force.com/analytics/home).

We don't really use it, but the "B2B Marketing Analytics App", which uses Tableau CRM Analytics Studio, was enabled as part of our Pardot implementation.