# How do I get contact id that is associated with an event from Event Record Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am working on adding a custom aura component into the Event Record Page. The below is what I have for `.cmp`

```
<aura:component
    implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" 
    access="global"
    extensible="true"
>
  <aura:attribute name="canvasParams" type="String"/>
  <aura:attribute name="id" type="String"/>
  <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
  <aura:handler name="init"     value="{!this}"         action="{!c.doInit}"/>

  <force:canvasApp
    developerName="Canvas_App"
    parameters="{!v.canvasParams}" scrolling="yes" height="100%" width="100%"
  />
</aura:component>
```

The following is the controller

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        const id = `MeetingInsightsController${Math.floor(
            Math.random() * 1000
        )}`;
        component.set("v.id", id);

        component.set("v.canvasParams", JSON.stringify({
            id: id,
            localhost: true,
            redirectPath: "to/our/own/web.html",
        }));

        console.log(component.get("v.recordId")) // not the id I want
    },
})
```

`v.recordId` isn't working because it gets the record id for the event rather than the contact associated to the event.
I will prefer not to use server side controller

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a custom Apex method to get this information. Something like:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Id getContactId(Id eventId){
    return [SELECT WhoId FROM Event WHERE Id = :eventId].WhoId;
}
```

Then call this method from your Javascript, following these instructions: [Calling Server Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm)

Usually, we could use  the standard [Record Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/documentation) component for this, but this does not work for the Event object.

Comment: Thank you. This will get me the id for the contact, but I am curious is there a way to get the type, for example, lead or contact?

Comment: I would ask that as a separate question. But I think you'll find that it's already answered: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239069/retrieve-object-type-via-id-using-apex

Comment: Basically you can do `WhoId.getSObjectType()`